# Graph does not plot correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

I have studied, Python, Kivy, Postgres, Peewee, Django, Pandas and now Dash.

I only started this way because in Telegram and Whatsapp groups I have been asked a lot of questions about my knowledge that are running things over.

But you are right, I usually do that, however, I think that my doubt could be answered without enigmas, without hurt anyone but I want to say that I am not a professional programmer, I don't have a paid activity, everything is fun.

Let's get to what really matters:

I can't plot a line graph as I have been told that I am indexing the data, I don't know where I am doing this.

Can someone help me plot this chart without errors?

[My code](https://gist.github.com/CoutinhoElias/a22c18e3bbc993dc590cf1580731c798)

Comment: The code you link to is not calling `matplotlib` anywhere.  You need to show us the entire traceback.

Answer (score 1):

For creating a graph, it is usually used with matplotlib.
I looked at your code and successfully run it, but I do not think this is something that you like to do, so I plot your data by using matplotlib.

[image: Evento X]

MesAno has type string, so let's convert to something comparable.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(str(movimento_por_mes_vendedores['MesAno'].iloc[1]), '%Y-%m')

movimento_por_mes_vendedores['MesAno'] = movimento_por_mes_vendedores['MesAno'].fillna(0) #NANを0置換
for i in range(0, movimento_por_mes_vendedores.shape[0]):
    movimento_por_mes_vendedores['MesAno'].iloc[i] = datetime.strptime(str(movimento_por_mes_vendedores['MesAno'].iloc[i]), '%Y-%m')
```

And store those data in list

```
postDatedList = []

for i in range(0, movimento_por_mes_vendedores.shape[0]):
    postDatedList.append(datetime(
        movimento_por_mes_vendedores['MesAno'].iloc[i].year,
        movimento_por_mes_vendedores['MesAno'].iloc[i].month,
        movimento_por_mes_vendedores['MesAno'].iloc[i].day
    ))

debitAmountList = []
for i in range(0, movimento_por_mes_vendedores.shape[0]):
    debitAmountList.append(movimento_por_mes_vendedores['qtitem'].iloc[i])
print("post shape: " + str(len(debitAmountList)))
```

Then you can compare those two with matplotlib

```
x = postDatedList
y = debitAmountList

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,10), dpi=100, facecolor='white')

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y, width=20, align="center")
ax.xaxis_date()

plt.title('Financial Graph')
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Amount")
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]